# Change label text on toggle

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently have a working dark mode switch in my browser, that when i toggle on, my website becomes black, and when i toggle off, my website becomes white.

But the thing is, i want to change the "Dark Mode" label beside the toggle such that the text change to "Light Mode" when toggle is off and "Dark Mode" when toggle is on.

How do i do it?

Here is a current picture of how it looks like(Note: the word "Dark" does not changes at all with the switch)
[image]

The extract from HTML:

```html
<div class="nav-link">
     <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
       <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="darkSwitch" />
       <label class="custom-control-label" for="darkSwitch">Dark Mode</label>
     </div>

     <!-- Javascript For Darkmode Switch -->
     <script src="index.js"></script>
</div>
```

The extract from javascript:

```js
const darkSwitch = document.getElementById("darkSwitch");
function initTheme() {
  const e =
    null !== localStorage.getItem("darkSwitch") &&
    "dark" === localStorage.getItem("darkSwitch");
  (darkSwitch.checked = e),
    e
      ? document.body.setAttribute("data-theme", "dark")
      : document.body.removeAttribute("data-theme");
}
function resetTheme() {
  darkSwitch.checked
    ? (document.body.setAttribute("data-theme", "dark"),
      localStorage.setItem("darkSwitch", "dark"))
    : (document.body.removeAttribute("data-theme"),
      localStorage.removeItem("darkSwitch"));
}
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  darkSwitch &&
    (initTheme(),
    darkSwitch.addEventListener("change", () => {
      resetTheme();
    }));
});
```

The extract from CSS:

```css
[data-theme="dark"] {
  background-color: #111 !important;
  color: #eee;
}

[data-theme="dark"] .bg-light {
  background-color: #333 !important;
}

[data-theme="dark"] .bg-white {
  background-color: #000 !important;
}

[data-theme="dark"] .bg-black {
  background-color: #eee !important;
}

/* CSS For table */
[data-theme="dark"] .table {
  background-color: #111 !important;
  color: #eee;
}
```

Comment: In my opinion, the JavaScript is trying a little too hard to be clever. The overuse of the ternary and comma operators just makes it harder to read and will lead to bugs as other people are asked to modify the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an ID to the text you want to change, in your case :

```
<label class="custom-control-label" id="modelLabel" for="darkSwitch">Dark Mode</label>
```

and update your resetTheme() function as follow:

```
function resetTheme() {
  var modelLabel = document.getElementById("modelLabel");

  if(darkSwitch.checked){
    (document.body.setAttribute("data-theme", "dark"),
      localStorage.setItem("darkSwitch", "dark"));

    modelLabel.innerHTML = "Light Mode";
  }
  else{
    (document.body.removeAttribute("data-theme"),
      localStorage.removeItem("darkSwitch"));

        modelLabel.innerHTML = "Dark Mode";
  }  
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Give a ID for label and change text using DOM.

```
<label class="custom-control-label" for="darkSwitch" id="darkLabel">Dark Mode</label>
```

```js
var label=document.getElementById("darkLabel");
label.innertHTML="Dark Mode"; //If Light Mode
label.innertHTML="Light Mode"; //If Dark Mode
```

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the text from the label and use css `:before` to add the content there.

```
[for="darkSwitch"]:before{
  content:'Dark Mode'
}

[data-theme="dark"] [for="darkSwitch"]:before{
  content:'Light Mode'
}
```

Demo at https://jsfiddle.net/ju2n3svy/